# is there any chance for onkeypress function in all-time situation

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function which have onkeypress function in it but it works just very first time. What I have to do for run this function every key press?

Comment: Cant comment without seeing the code

Comment: in which language? where? when? why? Your question is rising many other questions?

Comment: someone starred this question... Awesome stuffff

Comment: @khan Well it's tagged Javascript so I would guess Javascript. And *where* is not really applicable.

Comment: I am using my cell phone to write this because of that I am not able to write my codes to here but you can see the real page: http://www.tvdebugunnevar.com/a/

Comment: That... is some horrible code right there...

Comment: thnx @WaleedKhan you really helped me and quit my confusion but I just want to show him that this is the wrong way to ask a question.

Comment: I think you didn't paste the right link

Comment: @khan It looks like the right link to me.

Comment: @WaleedKhan then where is the press event on it?I want you to explain me what is in the link relevant to this question?

Comment: @khan Line 15: `document.keypress = ...`

Comment: @WaleedKhan sorry I jz saw the source :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.write` creates a new page, which won't have any event handlers. Or any other content, for that matter.

Comment: what I have to use other than document.write in this situation?

Comment: @user1783032 [DOM manipulation methods](http://www.google.com/search?q=DOM+manipulation).